# How to load font URI's into a shadowDOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

I am rendering an SVG with text inside a shadow DOM for a chrome plugin I am building. This shadow DOM has CSS, including a few fonts that I append directly into it as uris with the following JavaScript code:

```
 var modalHolder = document.querySelector("#modalHolder")
 var shadowRoot = modalHolder.shadowRoot

 var merriweatherStyle = document.createElement("style");
 merriweatherStyle.textContent = merriweatherCSSRules //merriWeatherCSS
 shadowRoot.prepend(merriweatherStyle) 

 var robotoStyle = document.createElement("style");
 robotoStyle.textContent = robotoCSSRules
 shadowRoot.prepend(robotoStyle)
```

Below is how robotoCSSRules appears in the shadow DOM when the plugin loads on the browser

```
<style>@font-face { font-family: Roboto; font-style: italic; font-weight: 400; font-display: swap; src: local("Roboto Italic"), local("Roboto-Italic"), url("data:font/woff2;base64,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…
</style>
```

I append text to the SVG and assign font-family with the following D3 code:

```
const quoteText = textGroup.append("text")
            .attr("class", "quoteText")
            .style("font-size", "50px") 
            .style("font-family", 'Merriweather')
            .attr("fill", text_color)
            .text("My test text")
```

Unfortunately, the font families do not appear to be loading correctly with this method. The text that is appended to the SVG (with D3.js) renders with the default font-family of the DOM.

Is there a way to fix this?

I can provide more context if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have checked out [these](https://medium.com/rate-engineering/winning-the-war-of-css-conflicts-through-the-shadow-dom-de6c797b5cba) [resources](https://robdodson.me/at-font-face-doesnt-work-in-shadow-dom/) which recommend adding the font face import into the regular DOM. While this does allow the font to render correctly, it unfortunately does not seem to be a useful option for me. This is because I am running some text wrapping calculations require the font-family to be applied before the SVG is loaded into regular DOM.